# How to switch to cc-mode programatically (from elisp code)

Tags: major-mode

In my lisp code, I need to switch to cc-mode, do something and back to original mode (text mode). How to do that ?

Comment: You can simply call those functions; but... why do you need to do that?  If you elaborate, other solutions might become clear.

Comment: in particular, I want to call (indent-region) on a block of C code to format it, but the document is not a C source file.

Comment: You should add that information to the question. Be specific!

Comment: I wonder if this is a duplicate question. This is essentially just asking how to switch to a different major mode temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you want to compose function calls in a sequence, you just put them one after the other inside of a function, like this:

```lisp
(defun do-the-thing ()
  (interactive)
  (cc-mode)
  (indent-region)
  (normal-mode))
```

There are a few cases where you need to use `progn` instead, but we’ll leave that for the advanced course.

Comment: Unfortunatly,calling it it gave me error: "Symbol’s function definition is void: cc-mode"

Comment: Use whatever mode you want the buffer to be in. Several modes, such as `c-mode` and `c++-mode` and `java-mode` and so on are derived from `cc-mode`. Let me know which one you want and I will edit the answer.